# public classes of swiftui xcframework are not in scope in another SwiftUI iOS App

Tags: swiftui, xcframework

I have created an xcframework in SwiftUI with public classes and structs.

When I add this framework in my other SwiftUI iOS app via Target >> General >> Framework, library, Embedded Content. It gets added successfully and I am able to import that too

Still, I am not able to access the public classes and pass on the data to the framework

```
import MobileSDK

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        
        // To get a view with all UI
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Host App"))
```

***Error that I get MyBridge and DataModel are not n scope***

```
        let bridge = MyBridge(dataModel: DataModel(myToken: token))
    }
}
```

}

SDK / xcframework file code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public struct DataModel {
    var myToken: String
    
    public init(myToken: String){
        self.myToken = myToken
    }
}

public class MyBridge {
    
    private var dataModel: DataModel

    public init(dataModel: DataModel) {
        self.dataModel = dataModel
    }
    
    public func launch() {
        
    }
}
```

Commands used to create xcframework

xcodebuild archive -scheme MobileSDK -destination="iOS Simulator" -archivePath /tmp/Projects/iossimulator.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/Projects/iphoneos -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild archive -scheme MobileSDK -destination="iOS" -archivePath /tmp/Projects/ios.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/Projects/iphoneos -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "/private/tmp/Projects/iossimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MobileSDK.framework" -framework "/private/tmp/Projects/ios.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MobileSDK.framework" -output /tmp/Projects/MobileSDK.xcframework

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but this is a **question** and answer site. You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Not able to get what u expect, I have shared all important details only along with code

Answer (score 0):

Excluding Architecture arm64 from simulator helped me resolve this issue